# Using XPath in ElementTree to find Nested Elements

Tags: python, elementtree

Given the following xml example, how can I print both the Actor name and their location?

I would like for the output to be:

John Cleese
Ohio
Eric Idle
Colorado

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<actors xmlns:fictional="http://characters.example.com"
        xmlns="http://people.example.com">
    <actor>
        <name>John Cleese</name>
        <fictional:character>Lancelot</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Archie Leach</fictional:character>
        <Location>
            <State>
                <name>Ohio</>
            </State>
        </Location>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Eric Idle</name>
        <fictional:character>Sir Robin</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Gunther</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Commander Clement</fictional:character>
        <Location>
            <State>
                <name>Colorado</>
            </State>
        </Location>
    </actor>
</actors>
```

I tried the below code but it only prints the actor's names and does not print the states names

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Actors.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

root = fromstring(xml_text)
for actor in root.findall('{http://people.example.com}actor'):
    name = actor.find('{http://people.example.com}name')
    print(name.text)
    for state in actor.findall('{http://characters.example.com}state'):
        print(' |-->', state.text)
```

Comment: You will have better chances of getting help if you show some research (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
actors = root.findall('.//{*}actor')
for actor in actors:
    name = actor.find('./{*}name')
    location = actor.find('./{*}Location//{*}name')
    print(name.text, location.text)
```

Output:

```
John Cleese Ohio
Eric Idle Colorado
```

Comment: Hi Jack, just out of curiosity, what if there is more than one state, how could I grab both?

<actor>
        <name>Eric Idle</name>
        <fictional:character>Sir Robin</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Gunther</fictional:character>
        <fictional:character>Commander Clement</fictional:character>
        <Location>
            <state>
                <name>Colorado</>
            </state>
     <state>
  <name>Texas</>
     </state> 
        </Location>
    </actor>

Comment: @Clyde I believe it's doable, but may be too long for a comment. It's probably best to just post it as a separate question.